# Conditional formatting in Excel for totals

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
X        Y        Z  
1        5        0  
1        4        0  
1        9        1  
2        5        0  
2        4        0  
2        **8**    1
```

Basically, I have an excel table with 3 variables. X is an group variable, Y is a value, and Z is a dummy variable that indicates if the Y value in that row is a total or not. Is there any way to write the conditional formatting rule so that discrepancies between SUM(Y) over the same X, and the supposed total are highlighted?

In the table above, The third row with X would not be marked because 5+4=9, so there is no discrepancy, but the 6th row would be marked because 5+4!=8, so that one should be highlighter. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SUMIFS();

Assuming your data starts in A1

```
=AND(SUMIFS($B:$B,$A:$A,$A1,$C:$C,0)<>$B1,$C1=1)
```

Apply it to B:B.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! 
That worked beautifully. If you don't mind me asking, what would I need to change in the formula so it does not highlight missing values. I.e Z=1, but Y is missing?